# Convert Char PK/FK to Varchar or RTRIM everywhere?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

We have a DB with a few hundred tables that have a CHAR "Code" field used for various ressources. This code field is the primary key and foreign key for multiple tables.

We now display this code on mouseover of the ressource in our ASP.NET application and when the code is shorter than the CHAR field length, it displays white spaces. We fix this through RTRIMing (which is often overlooked).

1. We'll only have a few 10s to low 100s of active users so performance impact shouldn't be that big
2. Would there be a way to automatically drop and recreate all PK/FK constraints while converting from CHAR TO VARCHAR? I've looked a bit at INFORMATION_SCHEMA and it looks like it would be feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience `char` causes many problems, not only unexpected spaces in the front-end:

- There's logic errors when a comparison doesn't account for the trailing spaces.
- When you ask for the `len()`: does it return the length of the string including or excluding spaces?
- `char` consumes more disk space than necessary. Since a primary key is included in every index for its table, this can add up to a non-trivial amount of space.

So it's typically a good idea to refactor from `char` to `varchar`.

Depending on the number of tables you have, this can be quite a lot of work.  You'd first have to drop every contraint that references the columns.  Then you'd:

```
alter YourTable alter column YourColumn varchar(50) primary key
```

After that you would re-add constraints.  You will find that it takes a lot of trying to add/remove the constraints in the right order.  For example, a `foreign key` requires a `unique` constraint on the referenced column.  So you'd have to drop the `foreign key` before the `unique` constraint.

`Right click database -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts` would provide you with a lot of the statements for re-creating the constraints, if not always in the correct order.

Comment: The comparisons in SQL are fine (whitespace ignored) but comparisons in the c# code causes problem because sometimes coders will RTRIM the value and compare it against a non-RTRIM'd value.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't make a decision on whether to use `char` or `varchar` based on how the value is displayed on the front end.

If you are having to add `rtrim` everywhere, you could instead create a view around the table that contains this field, and perform the `rtrim` only once inside the view.

However, since it sounds like your field isn't always 5 characters, `varchar` may be more appropriate.

Unfortunately, there's no automated way to do this.  You'll have to drop all of your primary and foreign key constraints, change the data type, and then re-add the constraints.

Comment: Make it an updatable view, rename the base table, and give the new, updatable view the name of the old base table.

Comment: The problem with views is sometimes we'll want the actual key for logic comparisons and sometimes we'll want the RTRIM'd version for displaying. For this reason I tend to prefer to go for a varchar conversion